# Ubuntu Amazon EC2 Connecting using IMAP

Tags: telnet, imap, google

I have been trying to connect to IMAP on my Ubuntu Server on Amazon EC2, however, I fail to find the reason why it won't be able to connect. I use the following command to test:

```
telnet imap.gmail.com imap
```

Comment: What happens? What doesn't happen (that would you expect to happen)? What error messages do you get? (If none, say so.) What does the documentation for Google's IMAP implementation say about connecting?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for Google's IMAP implementation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) is explicit on this matter:

> - Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server: imap.gmail.com
> - Requires SSL: Yes
> - Port: 993

You cannot use `telnet` to talk to an SSL-enabled port. (At least, not usefully; `telnet imap.gmail.com imaps` won't get you very far.) You could use the OpenSSL toolkit though

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:imaps
```